# Disable Clean Url in database

Tags: 6, media, uri

I am migrating a site from Apache to IIS.

When I backed up the database Clean Urls was active, now my links do not work and I have to add **?q=** to them!  Some links work well but the Admin pages are not shown and they display a white screen!

How can I disable Clean Urls?

Also, my images that are customized with ImageCache are not showing!  They return a link to a broken image.

Answer (score 9):

Edit settings.php and add:

```
$conf = array(
  'clean_url' => 0,
);
```

Use drush:

```
drush vset clean_url 0
```

You can also edit the database as well.

Comment: how to use drush? or database?
please help me more...?

Comment: With phpMyAdmin open the variables table and change the value of clean_url to 0.

Comment: Your choice - If you have Drush installed, it is much easier. (see: https://www.drupal.org/node/5590)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where I created a site on my testing server then migrated it to a shared hosting environment and I couldn't get any inner pages to work due the the URLs being rewritten.  But mod-rewrite wasn't turned on on the shared hosting environment so I kept getting a 500 Internal error.  Here's what I did in settings.php for Drupal 7.

```
/*
 * Turning off clean urls
 */
$conf['clean_url'] = 0;
```

It worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

If you need deactivate the clean URL from database you can try with

```
UPDATE  `variable` SET  `value` =0 WHERE  `name` =  'clean_url'
```